# Postfix - smtp.mailfrom domain of a php app

Tags: php, postfix

How to setup Postfix/PHP to have the smtp.mailfrom in the form of wordpress@wordpress-site-domain.tld?
I have multiple users on the server, and each one has one or more WordPress installations, but all mails coming from WP have host1234.hostingprovider.tld as their smtp.mailfrom.
Is there a way to have the postfix detect the domain the wp_mail is sending from(as the shared hosting solutions do)?

Answer (score 0):

In the *php.ini* file, setting:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f postmaster@example.com
```

changed the `smtp.mailfrom=` value in the outgoing email. This required a php-fpm and nginx restart.

Conversely, setting `sendmail_from` in the *php.ini* had no effect.

Also, using PHP [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function setting either the additional headers parameter (4th):

```
$headers = 'From: postmaster@example.com';
```

, or additional params parameter (5th):

```
$params = '-f postmaster@example.com';
```

...changed the `smtp.mailfrom=` value in the outgoing email.

Prior to making these changes the `smtp.mailfrom=` value contained the "nginx" username, i.e., nginx@example.com

*Server:* Almalinux 8, nginx, php-fpm, postfix